# Any other Alternative of Cross Join

Tags: sql-server

I have query with cross join in it. its taking too much time for execution.

Query:

```
select a.id as Fid,a.name as FName,curr.store_id, curr.period, curr.transaction_year, curr.sales as sales, curr.profits AS profitMargin,
old.sales as lastYearSales, old.profits as lastYearProfitMargin
from
(
    select store_id,period ,transaction_year,sales as sales,
    profits as profits,volume ,profit_margin 
    from  xyz.StoreData
    where 
      transaction_year = 2016
)curr
left outer join 
(
    select store_id,period ,transaction_year,sales,profits,volume ,profit_margin 
    from  xyz.StoreData
    where 
       transaction_year = 2015
) old
on 
    curr.store_id = old.store_id
CROSS JOIN
    xyz.functions a
```

the Table functions have only 4 to 5 Records in it, but Store data Table have more than 20000 records.

When i am running this into SSMS With execution Plan there is a warning of "No Join Predicates".( with 9% Cost).

is there any other alternative of cross join for better performance?

Comment: Is `transaction_year` value unique in `StoreData`? A single row per year for each `store_id`?

Comment: If you really logically need that cross join, then even an index won't help in the functions table, because every record from both sides has to be matched with every other record.  Maybe you can tell us why you think you need a cross join.

Comment: If `cross join` is logically the correct thing to do here, no, there's no "magic cross join but fast" option to use.

Comment: Nope there are different stores which have data  at store level sales in the table with year.

Comment: There is no column in the Storedata table to map with functions, and i need all the stores mapped with the all the functions at the UI view irrespective of the sales data. i.e. so i used that query with cross Join!!

Comment: I meant a tuple of `(transaction_year, store_id)`. If it's not unique then query is totally broken. `MISSING JOIN PREDICATE` warnings are confirming that. Hovewer the code with no join predicates is not present in given part of your query.

Comment: `at the UI view irrespective of the sales data` remove those `cross joins` from DB and solve your UI problems at UI code. Call several queries and utilize their output as you wish.

Comment: Yes Ivan Starostin you are right but i have a View for this data and the query is like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e469a/1/0